# codeigniter form_radio problem

Tags: forms, codeigniter, select, boolean

Hello i want to use the form_radio in codeigniter, and i want the first to be selected, but how can i do that ?, i have this now

```
<div style="float:left;">Dreng:</div> <?php echo form_radio('dreng', '1', true, 'class=radio'); ?> 
<div style="float:left;">Pige:</div> <?php echo form_radio('pige', '2', false, 'class=radio'); ?>
```

Comment: can you show what html that renders?

Answer (score 2):

You have to give it a reason to default to on. If you are calling this HTML on a create page, use the lack of $_POST as a sign to default.

```
<div style="float:left;">Dreng:</div> <?php echo form_radio('dreng', '1', empty($_POST), 'class=radio'); ?> 
<div style="float:left;">Pige:</div> <?php echo form_radio('pige', '2', false, 'class=radio'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are these two radio buttons belong to the same group? it sounds like they are! if so then you have to use the same `name` field:

```
<div style="float:left;">Dreng:</div> <?php echo form_radio('group_name', '1', true, 'class=radio'); ?> 
<div style="float:left;">Pige:</div> <?php echo form_radio('group_name', '2', false, 'class=radio'); ?>
```